# comprehensive SELECT syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, syntax

I've been looking for a single query which shows the syntax order of a SELECT statement in SQL.

Database engine is unimportant, I just want to see the simplest and most varied expression of a select query, in terms of clauses used.

Below is my first attempt, each clause is used once and with appropriate syntax:

```
SELECT AVG/MIN/MAX/SUM/COUNT/DISTINCT(field_list) AS custom_name
FROM table1
JOIN field_list2
ON table2_field_to_join_on
= table1_field_to_join_on
WHERE condition
GROUP BY field_list_condition
HAVING conditions
ORDER BY field_list_order_condition ASC(default)/DESC
LIMIT number_of_records;
```

I'm just looking for a more comprehensive version of the above.

EDIT: In retrospect, it makes sense why this was marked as unclear. I won't delete the question since the answer helped me get to where I wanted, and it might help others down the line too.

Comment: With the greatest respect, why? Trying to make this cross platform will be a nightmare.

Comment: One reason could be to simply show the syntax order for more complex query. Another one might be to teach beginners of the various expressions they might not be aware of. Of course there is documentation, but I've never come across a holistic query wherein all expressions are used. I guess to me this would showcase the power of SQL in a single unified window. (perhaps excluding the various arithmetic that can be done, so as to keep it simplified and SQL-unique only)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

```
SELECT
[ALL | DISTINCT | DISTINCTROW ]
  [HIGH_PRIORITY]
  [MAX_STATEMENT_TIME = N]
  [STRAIGHT_JOIN]
  [SQL_SMALL_RESULT] [SQL_BIG_RESULT] [SQL_BUFFER_RESULT]
  [SQL_CACHE | SQL_NO_CACHE] [SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS]
select_expr [, select_expr ...]
[FROM table_references
  [PARTITION partition_list]
[WHERE where_condition]
[GROUP BY {col_name | expr | position}
  [ASC | DESC], ... [WITH ROLLUP]]
[HAVING where_condition]
[ORDER BY {col_name | expr | position}
  [ASC | DESC], ...]
[LIMIT {[offset,] row_count | row_count OFFSET offset}]
[PROCEDURE procedure_name(argument_list)]
[INTO OUTFILE 'file_name'
    [CHARACTER SET charset_name]
    export_options
  | INTO DUMPFILE 'file_name'
  | INTO var_name [, var_name]]
[FOR UPDATE | LOCK IN SHARE MODE]]
```

Obviously this is mysql-specific, but it gives a pretty good flavour.